# How to Fetch and Publish the latest data and list data in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

[image]I am currently working on django , Need some help how to achive my below goal

I need to publish the latest data  and list data in a web app .

Below is  the set of steps i followed

Created the Model.py

import datetime
from statistics import mode
from django.db import models

## Create your models here.

```
class documents(models.Model):
    author= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description=models.TextField()
    creation_date=models.DateTimeField()
    update_date=models.DateTimeField()
```

View.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import documents

    # Create your views here.
    
    
    
    
    class documentlist(ListView):
        template_name='app/document_list.html'
        model=documents
        context_object_name='document'
```

HTML snippet

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title %} MY HOMEPAGE {% endblock  %}

{% block css %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

{% endblock  %}


{% block content %}


<nav class=" navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#">MEDICARE</a>
  </nav>

{% for d in document  %}

 <td>{{d.title}}</td>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

How can we render both latest data and list of data from a model class in django?I am clear about rendering the list data using listview . can someone help in understanding how to display the latest data from the list to the listview.html

Thanks,Sid

Comment: You should detail what is your latest data you want (as it can be a few things... pk, creation_date, update_date...)

Comment: hi Em1le, i just need to show the latest data(updat_date) as fetured in html and parallely i need to show the list of the items in the same html page

Comment: I have added a new image for the requirement. I  need to show my latest post as the fetaured one and  i  need to  show the list as list view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you would go about getting your recent publish data in your listview like this:

```
class documentlist(ListView):
        template_name='app/document_list.html'
        model=documents
        context_object_name='document'
        
        def get_queryset(self):
            return documents.objects.filter(author=request.user).order_by('creation_date')
```

in your html template you can do something like this to render the latest post

```
% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title %} MY HOMEPAGE {% endblock  %}

{% block css %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

{% endblock  %}


{% block content %}


<nav class=" navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#">MEDICARE</a>
  </nav>

{% for doc in document  %}

 <td>{{doc.title}}</td>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the issue and this helped me resolve the issue.

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['latest_post'] = documents.objects.latest('update_date')
        return context
```

Thanks,
SIdh

Answer (score 0):

Just add ordering by id in descending order:

```
 class documentlist(ListView):
        template_name='app/document_list.html'
        model=documents
        context_object_name='document'

        ordering = ['-id']
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have this added , i am able to order the data in list ,which i am aware of it .But i need to show the latest  data as the latest post and show as a fetured one , i have attached screenshot as per my requirement.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this post is old enough but not closed yet, it may be useful for someone else.

> But i need to show the latest data as the latest post and show as a
> fetured one , i have attached screenshot as per my requirement
> Facing this equation this is how I did:
> [My view:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwQz3.png)

[And this is my template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEK3B.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).